# html5 file upload asp mvc vs php

Tags: php, asp.net-mvc, html, file-upload

I like this multi file upload:

http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-javascript-file-upload-progress-bar/

but the backend sample is in php, can someone help me convert it to asp.net mvc3, or a nice starting point, not sure where to begin:

```
<?php
$fn = (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILENAME']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILENAME'] : false);
if ($fn) {

    // AJAX call
    file_put_contents('uploads/' . $fn,file_get_contents('php://input'));
    echo "$fn uploaded";
    exit();
}
else {
    // form submit
    $files = $_FILES['fileselect'];
    foreach ($files['error'] as $id => $err) {
        if ($err == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
            $fn = $files['name'][$id];
            move_uploaded_file($files['tmp_name'][$id],'uploads/' . $fn);
            echo "<p>File $fn uploaded.</p>";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just create an action that takes an `HttpPostedFileBase fileselect` as a parameter.

MVC will do the rest.